# Converting results from sqflite to custom object type (Unhandled Exception: type 'QueryRow' is not a subtype of type 'Attendee')

Tags: flutter

I would like to convert the results returned from sqflite to a list of objects with a custom type `Attendee`

Below is how I do it:

```
Future<List<Attendee>> _findManyAttendees(billId) async {
    List<Attendee> attendees = <Attendee>[];
    final results =
        await LocalStorageService.instance.findManyAttendees(billId);

    debugPrint('_findManyAttendees Results: $results');

    results.forEach((itemMap) => {attendees.add(itemMap)});

    return results;
  }
```

However, the code above returns the following error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'QueryRow' is not a subtype of type 'Attendee'
```

How can I convert the results from database to `List<Attendee> attendees`?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should use `map` on the results to convert them to `Attendee` before you try to append them to the attendees list. Or better yet, just use `results.map(...).toList()` and get rid of the attendees list entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is because of you are adding object of `QueryRow` to a list of `Attendee` that they are not the same.

```
Future<List<Attendee>> _findManyAttendees(billId) async {
  final results = await LocalStorageService.instance.findManyAttendees(billId);
  debugPrint('_findManyAttendees Results: $results');

  // Use the `map` method to convert the query results into a list of Attendee objects
  final attendees = results.map((itemMap) => Attendee.fromMap(itemMap)).toList();

  return attendees;
}
```

and for example this is the model of `Attendee` and you can change it because I do not know exactly about data members but note that use `fromMap` method.

```
class Attendee {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final int billId;

  Attendee({required this.id, required this.name, required this.billId});

  factory Attendee.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Attendee(
      id: map['id'],
      name: map['name'],
      billId: map['bill_id'],
    );
  }
}
```

happy coding...